# Discord.js How to send only image/photo url in chat

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made code that let bot delete message are not **url image** not file, and i don't know how it works and this is what i tried but doesn't work.

```js
let myMessage = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');

if(!myMessage.startsWith('https://') && !myMessage.endsWith('png' || 'jpeg' || 'jpg')){
    message.channel.send(`This is not a picture (**${myMessage}**)`)
    .then(m => m.delete(10000));
    message.delete();
    return;
}
client.user.setAvatar(`${myMessage}`);
```

Comment: Why are you deleting the message twice? (`.then(m => m.delete(1000));` and `message.delete();`)

Comment: `message.delete();` delete user message `.then(m => m.delete(1000));` delete error message.

Comment: Ok. So you are checking if `myMessage` is a url. But even if it is no url, you are setting the client's avatar. I think you are missing an `else`..

Comment: yes i want change bot avatar but if the message don't start with `https://` and! don't end with `png` it's return error message to user

Comment: @Xge Inside the `if` block, there's a `return` statement preventing any further code from executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting in case anyone else comes across this thread like me:

I don't think the other answer works with multiple filetypes or protocols, so here is a regex solution that works.

```
    //if the message was a url that ends in png, jpg or jpeg
    if (/^(http|https):\/\/.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/i.test(message.content)) {
        //do the thing
        client.user.setAvatar(message.content);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working with urls.

```js
if(!myMessage.startsWith('https://')){
    message.channel.send(`This is not a picture (**${myMessage}**)`)
    return;
}else if(!myMessage.endsWith('png' && 'jpg')){
    message.channel.send(`This is not a picture (**${myMessage}**)`)
    return;
}else{
    bot.user.setAvatar(`${myMessage}`);
    message.channel.send(`Avatar Changed!! **${message.author.username}**`)
}
```

Comment: not sure where either of you got putting || and && in .endsWith because the docs say it's a string and also neither seem to work